# Postgres: How the fulltext search work with TSVECTORS and TSQUERY

Tags: postgresql

I use the fulltext search of postgres with tsvectors and tsquerys.
In my tsvector i have the entry like:

```
("'22305':3 'de':2 'kingsroad':4 'winterfell':1",)
```

when I now query to this tsvector with:

```
SELECT * FROM table
JOIN othertable ON othertable.id = table.id
WHERE othertable.tsvector @@ to_tsquery('<value>')
```

I get a different result. In case I search with the string

> 'kingsroad'

I get a the expected data. When the string is

> 'winterfell'

I don't. Instead I get nothing.

The way I understood tsvectors was that postgres matches the value agains all strings in the TSVECTOR. So I don't understand how I don't get the data both times.

Some additional infos:

I have a tsvector column in each table. I create the index with:

```
create index othertable_search_index on othertable using gin(search_tsvector)
```

And have set a trigger:

```
create trigger othertable_search_update before update or
               insert on othertable
               for each row execute procedure
               tsvector_update_trigger(search_tsvector,'pg_catalog.german',
                                      attribute,
                                      attribute2,
                                      attribute3
                                      )
```

Comment: If you specify an explicit `config` for `tsvector`s, you should use that too for your `tsquery` values too: use `to_tsquery(config regconfig, query text)` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html -- if you did not specify a config, `default_text_search_config` will be used http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TEXT-SEARCH-CONFIG

Comment: since I never changed a bit at the config for tsvector I use the default one. But I still don't understand why the tsvector and tsquery doesn't match.

Comment: that's the point, you use an explicit `'pg_catalog.german'` on `tsvector`s, but another one (the `'default'`) on `tsquery`. They should match, in order to work properly.